# Is it possible to pause a unit test at a breakpoint in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, visual-studio-2019

when I run a unit test I would like the test to pause at a breakpoint, just like when I am debugging the code. I am using Nunit for a c# project in visual studio 2019.

Comment: Yes it is possible when you `Debug` the test. Try it and see.

Comment: Yes, just right click and choose to debug the tests.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!